# Unable to Push AWS ECR Images in tekton pipeline

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-ecr, tekton, kaniko

I created tekton pipeline on minikube as per this [link](https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/build-and-deploy-a-docker-image-on-kubernetes-using-tekton-pipelines/#create-a-pipelinerun) (Basically I'm pulling the repo from github and generating image and pushing it to ECR)

But in my case, I'm pushing the image to AWS ECR.

I configured credentials of AWS ECR on my cluster as per [this](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/tutorials/configuring_creds_for_aws_ecr/)

When I'm running the pipeline I'm getting the following error.

**Note:** For testing if my AWS credentials were configured correctly or not, I created a simple deployment spec file and ran it. The image is pulled and the application is running. But with tekton I'm getting 401 issue. Can someone help me with this issue, please?

```
INFO[0000] GET KEYCHAIN                                 
error checking push permissions -- make sure you entered the correct tag name, and that you are authenticated correctly, and try again: checking push permission for "12345678910.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test-api:latest": POST https://12345678910.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v2/test-api/blobs/uploads/: unexpected status code 401 Unauthorized: Not Authorized
```

Comment: have you checked the IAM permissions that the creds are associated with?

Comment: Hi @MuhammadHasan Yes, I've pull and push permissions

Comment: I could able to push image to ECR with docker push command. Which means I've access to ECR. But it is failing with Kaniko @MuhammadHasan

Comment: okay..well then maybe raise a ticket with the aws support